# Подскажите, как переписать запрос с двумя JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть три таблицы:

**users, job, marketing**

В **users** есть ячейка company, допустим, у троих пользователей там стоит 1.

Job, marketing - две таблицы, в которых хранятся объявления пользователей.

Нужно вывести на экран все объявления пользователей, у которых стоит company = 1

Составил такой запрос, однако он не работает. Проблема заключается в этой строке:

`WHERE u.company = 1`

Как я понял, нужно составить сам запрос по другому, потому что таблица внутри запроса доступна только на первом уровне вложенности подзапросов. Вот код, который есть на данный момент:

```
SELECT
  m.id,
  m.upid,
  m.subject,
  m.message,
  m.username,
  m.view,
  m.date
FROM marketing m
  JOIN users u
    ON m.username = u.username
  WHERE u.company = 1
UNION
(SELECT
  j.id,
  j.upid,
  j.subject,
  j.message,
  j.username,
  j.view,
  j.date
FROM job j
  JOIN job j1
    ON (j1.username = u.username)
WHERE u.company = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй запрос какой-то странный. Зачем вы джойните два job?

```
SELECT
  m.id,
  m.upid,
  m.subject,
  m.message,
  m.username,
  m.view,
  m.date
FROM marketing m
  JOIN users u
    ON m.username = u.username
  WHERE u.company = 1
UNION
SELECT
  j.id,
  j.upid,
  j.subject,
  j.message,
  j.username,
  j.view,
  j.date
FROM job j
  JOIN users u
    ON m.username = u.username
  WHERE u.company = 1
```

А вообще похоже, что `job` и `marketing` должны быть одной таблицей с полем-признаком `type`